# Mercurial Automatic Push on Client Push between 2 servers

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I would like to know how it would be possible to push automatically to bitbucket when I push from my local pc to my local central repository.
Let me explain:

This is a 2 server (bitbucket, local central repository(ubuntu server)) and a client setup.

Project A is hosted on bitbucket. 
Local central repository has a push-able clone of project A. 
Client has a push-able clone of ubuntu central repository.

The desired effect should be:

1. The client commits locally and in some point pushes (multiple commits) to central repository.
2. The ubuntu central repository should then push automatically to bitbucket.

How can step 2 be done?

Regards,

S. Mantziaris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a hook:

In your Ubuntu repository, edit the `.hg/hgrc` file to include the following:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg push default
```

This hook will execute after the push to the Ubuntu server has been completed (or a pull from the client to the Ubuntu if you ever do that) and it will push the changes to the default push target.  If BitBucket is not your default push target then you can change the push command accordingly.

Comment: this sounds simple. i will check it out and let you know.

Comment: the change did not fire. maybe because the push target is password protected. i must investigate further. Is there any place to look for a log file on the hooks???

Comment: You can store the password in the `hgrc` file if you're confident that nobody else will be able to access it.  The instructions are [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth).